# The number of permutations of given order

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, permutations, generating-functions, recurrences

I want to count the number of permutations of the given order $k$ in $S_n\;(\sigma^k=id,\sigma^l\neq id\;for\;l<k)$. I found some works about that problem, but they are more general than necessary. May be somebody knows how the recurrence view will look($k=3$ for example).

Comment: The same question was asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006752/number-of-permutations-of-order-k  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340297/finding-the-number-of-elements-of-particular-order-in-the-symmetric-group though they don't have complete answers.

Answer (score 6):

The exponential generating function for permutations of order dividing $k$ is
$$\exp\biggl(\sum_{d\mid k} \frac{x^d}{d}\biggr).$$
See, e.g., L. Moser and M. Wyman, [On solutions of $x^d = 1$ in symmetric groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/on-solutions-of-xd-1-in-symmetric-groups/8F90642D9472FA7326164E54BE3BE57B), Canad. J. Math., 7 (1955), 159-168.
These are permutations in which every cycle length divides $k$. You can find the exponential generating function for permutations of order $k$ from this by Möbius inversion; there won't be a simpler formula.